# Tools or methods for solving a bizarre integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in solving (or determining that no solution exists) the following equation
$$
f(x) + \int_{x^{-1}\tau}^1 f(xy)f(y)dy = G(x)
$$
for a function $f:[\tau,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given a target function $G:[\tau,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\tau\in(0,1)$.

For certain functions $G$, a viable approach to solving this is the fixed point iteration
$$
f_{n+1}(x) = G(x) - \int_{x^{-1}\tau}^1 f_n(xy)f_n(y)dy.
$$
In particular, this works if the right hand side $G$ is sufficiently small. However, for larger functions $G$ this naive fixed point iteration fails to converge (I have observed this numerically). I also believe that it is possible that for certain functions $G$ the equation cannot be solved, although I have not been able to prove this.

Are there any techniques for approaching an non-linear integral equation of this form, either numerically or theoretically? Unfortunately, no amount of differentiating can remove the integral and give an ODE, since the integrand depends on $x$ in a non-trivial manner. Has anyone seen something similar before?

Comment: Are you working with a specific function $G(x)$ or looking for the general case?

Comment: I would be interested in the general case, but the specific class of functions I'm most interested in is $G(x) = Cx^{-\gamma}$ for $C,\gamma > 0$.

Comment: This is a longshot, but would it help to take one or two functional derivatives with respect to $f(\cdot)$? That would remove the integration and if you could obtain a formula for the functional derivative of $G$ then perhaps you could integrate it back more easily.